# Rewrite URI using directives

Tags: nginx

I want to re-write the following url:

```
http://example.com/contextpath/<token>/images/<image.png>
```

to

```
http://example.com/contextpath/images/<image.png>
```

the goal is to remove the token path. And point the location of static resources to:

```
location /contextpath/images{
            root    "C:/Temp/images";
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^(/contextpath)/[^/]+(/images/.*)$ $1$2 redirect;`